# Получение информации по ip

Tags: python, ip

Пишу скрипт для вычисления информации по ip, номеру телефона, gmail аккаунта.
Помогите написать скрипт для вычисления полной информации по ip как на сайте 2ip, а если можно прям с него

Comment: В каких именно благих целях Вы планируете использовать данную информацию?

Comment: ну например - https://pypi.org/project/2ip/

Comment: В любом случае вы не получите ту информацию которая вам не по праву.

Comment: Я хочу сделать программу, в ней будут параметры домтупа, к примеру чтоб в японии ну предположим, небыло доступа, или просто проверка возраста, чтобы контент с отметкой для 18+ небыл доступен, а так же что-бы обеспечить защиту.

Comment: У вас слишком объёмный вопрос, чтобы тут кто-то на него ответил. Начните с мелких конкретных вопросов - например, вычисление страны по Ip, проверка возраста и т.д.

Comment: @ИльМиль ну twoip для выяснения региона ip - вам будет достаточно

Comment: @CrazyElf, просто нужно чтобы питон работал в 2ip

Comment: страну в большинстве случаев можно определить. А вот возраст... тут сильно сложнее. А вот вычислить телефон по айпи ...

Comment: Нереально? В принципе можно попробывать вычеслить телефон, а потом позвонить и сделать проверку возраста

Comment: а теперь подумайте, что за одним айпи может сидеть целая куча людей (а в некоторых странах - до пол страны) (гуглить - NAT). И у одного человека может быть несколько телефонов, и может быть один телефон на несколько десятков людей. Вы прям как один наш банк, который свято верит, что у всех есть телефон с тачскрином.

Comment: Ок, мне нужна максимальная информация по ip которая только возможна

Comment: И ещё, нет ли способа зашифровать файл так, чтобы прочитал его только мой скрипт?

Comment: нет, такого способа в принципе нет.

Comment: Посмотрите тут https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IZOq_sOtLz0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [python3 -m pip install 2ip](https://pypi.org/project/2ip/)

```
>>> from twoip import TwoIP
>>> twoip = TwoIP(key = None)
>>> twoip.geo(ip = '8.8.8.8')
{'city': 'Mountain view',
 'country': 'United states of america',
 'country_code': 'US',
 'country_rus': 'США',
 'country_ua': 'США',
 'ip': '8.8.8.8',
 'latitude': '37.405992',
 'longitude': '-122.078515',
 'region': 'California',
 'region_rus': 'Калифорния',
 'region_ua': 'Каліфорнія',
 'time_zone': '-08:00',
 'zip_code': '94043'}
```